# Is there a way to preserve database file attributes(like UID, GID) while taking its backup

Tags: sqlite, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, busybox

We have beaglebone black based custom board,
We are adding application which runs as different user than root.
That application owns the sqlite database, with journal enabled.
But root user need to take backup of that database and preserve its file attributes like user, group and permissions.

Now I used following command to take a backup of sqlite database but file attributes like user and groups are not maintained file permissions are same, check below commands,

```
# ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 ankur    ankur        12288 Dec 20 15:46 testdb.sqlite
# 
# 
# 
# sqlite3 testdb.sqlite ".backup testdb_backup.sqlite"
# ls -l
-rw-r--r--    1 ankur    ankur        12288 Dec 20 15:46 testdb.sqlite
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         12288 Dec 20 15:47 testdb_backup.sqlite
```

Is there a different command(or options) to take a backup and maintain file attributes?

One of the option is to take a backup and copy source file attributes to destination(backup database).
But busybox `cp` doesn't support that.

Any other suggestion/pointer ?

Comment: why does the root user need to do that?

Comment: Because script which backs up the databases runs as root. It is common for all the databases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `su` or `sudo` to perform such actions that should behave as if the user had executed them.

In this case that would be *for example*

```
su -c 'sqlite3 testdb.sqlite ".backup testdb_backup.sqlite"' ankur
```

and

```
sudo -u ankur sqlite3 testdb.sqlite ".backup testdb_backup.sqlite"
```

`su` is available as a busybox command, you may need to enable it if your environment doesn't build busybox with it enabled.